Increase Allocated RAM Visual Studio Code On Newer VSCode versions
Is there a way I can increase allocated RAM on visual studio code? My computer has 128gb RAM but VSCode only uses about 1gb of it and as a result is incredibly slow.
Any help would be appreciated!
There is another answer on this forum for previous visual studio code using files.maxmMemoryForLargeFilesMB but that has been deprecated. What is the alternative for newer VSCode installations?
